# FFMpeg creates MP4 which no browser can decode, but it can be played in VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

How can I debug what happened? I've tried this with variations to generate a short video from a single image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i black.png -vcodec libx264 -b 1500k -s 640x360 -t 1 out.mp4
```

tried:

1. Changing aspect ration (or omitting it).
2. using `-image2` instead of `-loop`.
3. omitting bitrate.
4. creating longer videos.
5. also tried different syntax for specifying video codec: `-v:c libx264`.
6. tried mpeg instead of libx264.

In every case the effect is the same. The video plays in VLC, but not in the browser.

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option. See [FFmpeg x264 MP4 Encoding all grey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15281807/1109017), [flvEncoder .flv output won't convert to .mp4 with ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966616/1109017), [Convert EXR file sequence with FFmpeg and x264](http://superuser.com/a/512531/110524), and [How can I convert a series of PNG images to a video for YouTube?](http://superuser.com/a/533706/110524).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yes, thank you, that was it. Any idea why such a weird default? I was following ffmpeg's documentation / examples and they never even mention there are such parameters...

Comment: Can you provide a link to these examples? ffmpeg is technically doing what it should: preserving as much of the sample as supported by the encoder (specifically `libx264`). However, "dumb" players can not handle this so you have to be explicit in telling ffmpeg what you want since it can not guess. Unfortunately this can confuse users and some developers think `yuv420p` should be the default.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard FFMpeg track is down, [this google search link](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftrac.ffmpeg.org%2Fwiki%2FCreate%2520a%2520video%2520slideshow%2520from%2520images&ei=4ccLUr-7CNOz0QWCxYHgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGo5q28glYDSsfvVDmxw-mp7GX1Jw&sig2=d2VaMuvLEEAMPnM6UsRjXg) would be pointing at the page I took the example from. Well, especially if there is a dispute, I think it would be worthwhile to mention this in docs / examples. Also, the quality, given the context, is subjective. What if I understand quality in terms of speed?

Comment: Oh, here's another reference: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Answer (score 1):

Browsers require certain metadata about the movie to be in the front of the file in order to be able to start playing right away. ffmpeg can achieve this using the `-movflags faststart` option.

Try:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i black.png -vcodec libx264 -b 1500k -s 640x360 -t 1 -movflags faststart out.mp4
```

Note this does a second pass and will increase encoding time. Also be sure to be using a newer version of ffmpeg which supports this flag. More documentation can be found [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#MOV_002fMP4_002fISMV).